# scroll top and bottom with page control

Tags: ios6, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Using scrollview with page control for displaying different pages. want to scroll up and down on each page. How can i do that.

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3, self.view.frame.size.height)]; 

[scrollView setDelegate:self]; 

[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES]; 

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

// Add our views to the scroll view
[scrollView addSubview:pageOne.view];

[scrollView addSubview:pageTwo.view];

[scrollView addSubview:pageThree.view];

[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

_pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init]; 

[_pageControl setCurrentPage:0]; 

[_pageControl setNumberOfPages:3]; 

[_pageControl sizeToFit];

[_pageControl setFrame:CGRectMake((scrollView.frame.size.width / 2) - (_pageControl.frame.size.width / 2), scrollView.frame.size.height - _pageControl.frame.size.height, _pageControl.frame.size.width, _pageControl.frame.size.height)]; 

[self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
```

How can i enable scrolling up and down on each page.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to monitor the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event to determine when the page control has changed pages. You can do this programmatically view the `addTarget` method.

```
[_pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(positionChanged)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

This tells the page control to call the `positionChanged` method in the current object, whenever the page is changed. The `positionChanged` method can then look at the `currentPage` of the page control to determine where to move to.

So the `positionChanged` method might look something like this:

```
- (void)positionChanged {
  NSUInteger page = [_pageControl currentPage];
  CGFloat yoffset = self.view.frame.size.height * page;
  [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,y)];
}
```

Don't forget that you'll need to call `removeTarget` sometime before your object is destroyed, possibly in your `dealloc` method.

```
[_pageControl removeTarget:self action:@selector(positionChanged)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Code hasn't been tested, but hopefully that's enough to get you started.

If you don't want to do this programmatically, you can also connect your page control to the `positionChanged` method using the Xcode Interface Builder. The details are explained in the [Xcode User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW17).